Flickering screen when playing 3D games on 24.10 under Wayland
I'm experiencing some strange double buffering issue after upgrading to 24.10 when playing 3D games. It looks like the old display buffer is displayed time to time, causing a weird flickering effect.
For example in a game like Baldur's Gate 3, when I scroll down in a menu screen I see the new frame where the menu items moved, but then the next frame that is displayed is the old one, where the menu items are at their original position. Then it flickers back and forth between these two frames for a while, and eventually stops displaying the old frame.

Changing in the game from triple buffering to double buffering or no v-sync doesn't help.

When the game is running, all other windows flicker like this (the video player, Files, everything). When I exit the game, the rest of the windows start to behave normally.

This only happens under Wayland. Switching to X.org eliminates the problem.

This only affects the external screen. When the game uses the built-in screen of the laptop, it doesn't flicker (however all the other windows on the external screen do).


My laptop is an Asus ROG Zephyrus G14 with a Radeon RX 6800S graphics card.
Any ideas what may be the problem? Are there any settings that control double buffering under Wayland that I could try?
